# Why does only one instance of checkbox work if there are multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one application that multiple instances of it exists in the same page. I have one sort of slide show within the application that uses the `input` to show corresponding data. However the `label` and `input` only works with one instance in the page. so if there are to instance of the same application within the page, only the first one works.

Here is a demo: [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ukrmnq0v/)

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
};

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}

.panelTop > div input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input id="box-1" type="checkbox" checked>
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="box-2" type="checkbox">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="box-3" type="checkbox">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label for="box-1" class="btn1">1</label>
    <label for="box-2" class="btn2">2</label>
    <label for="box-3" class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input id="box-1" type="checkbox">
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="box-2" type="checkbox">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input id="box-3" type="checkbox">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label for="box-1" class="btn1">1</label>
    <label for="box-2" class="btn2">2</label>
    <label for="box-3" class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

So as you can see in the demo, there are two instances of the application, clicking on buttons of the `1, 2 or 3` makes change in the first instance even if you click on the second instance.

I want to make each instance work correctly and each radio button work only if it is pressed.

Any idea?

Comment: IDs should always be unique and never repeated.

Comment: also wrap that click code in `return this.each(function() { /* click code */ })` and you can combine your selectors and call plugin once

Comment: @DrydenLong Thanks for your comment.  Well I am looking for a method that is more dynamic. Since it is a part of an major application and it is not clear how many instances will be made, therefore it is not very easy/efficient to assign a unique id for 3 times in each instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dryden-long already mentioned, IDs must be unique. Fix that, and modify the corresponding `for` attributes accordingly, and your issue is resolved.

EDIT: Per your comment, since the `id` values of your `div.panel` elements are already unique, you could do something like the following, which dynamically generates unique `id` values for your `input` elements, and updates the `for` values of the corresponding `label` elements accordingly:

```js
$.fn.MP = function(options) {
  var settings = $.extend({
    // These are the defaults
    text: ""
  }, options);

  $(this).on("click tap", "input", function() {
    $(this).parent().siblings().find("input").prop("checked", false);
  });
};

// dynamically-generate id/for values
$('div.panel').each(function(index, el) {
    var $panel = $(el);
    var panelId = $panel.attr('id');
    var $panelBottom = $('div.panelBottom', $panel);

    $('div.panelTop > div > input', $panel).each(function(indexInput, elInput) {
        var $input = $(elInput);
        var inputId = panelId + '-box-' + indexInput;

        $input.attr('id', inputId);
        $('label:nth(' + indexInput + ')', $panelBottom).attr('for', inputId);
    });
});

$("#item1").MP({});
$("#item2").MP({});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}

.panelTop > div div {
  display: none;
}

.panelTop > div input[type="checkbox"]:checked ~ div {
  display: block;
}

.panel {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.panel > .panelTop {
  width: 100%;
  height: 49px;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}

.panel > .panelTop > div div {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  float: right;
  margin: 0px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.panel > .panelBottom > div {
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  float: right;
  margin: 9px 9px 0 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="panel" id="item1">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="item2">
  <div class="panelTop">
    Dependant Buttons:
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>1.1</div>
      <div>1.2</div>
      <div>1.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>2.1</div>
      <div>2.2</div>
      <div>2.3</div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox">
      <div>3.1</div>
      <div>3.2</div>
      <div>3.3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panelBottom">
    Main Buttons:
    <label class="btn1">1</label>
    <label class="btn2">2</label>
    <label class="btn3">3</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your, answer. it is absolutely working. However as I explained it up in the comments, I require a more dynamic solution where either unique id is not required or they are created and implemented  automatically. Any thoughts for that?